# Transforming datum after false introducing in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have gps coordinates. I introduced them to arcgis without transforming them from wgs 84 to ed1950. But they are not originally ed 1950. I created a lot features with those coordinates. Then I realized the points are not at the right place. In this circumstance, what to do for not to restarting the project.

ps 
My basemap has ed 1950 datum.

[image: After Kennedys reply, first i defined the related feature dataset to wgs84 then i tried to use "project tool" to convert. In "project tool" on the (optional) "geographical transformation" section it automatically adds a lot of ed_1950_to_wgs84_30 to list but it gave error so i couldn't end the process. Then i dropped all ed_1950_to_wgs_84_30's and i added a ed_1950_to_wgs_1984_1. For now it gives no error. But do i need to have a lot of ed_1950_to_wgs_1984_1 as proposed automatically? What is the difference between wgs_84_30 and wgs_84_1 or wgs_84_19 etc. shown in the figure?]

Comment: Use the Define Projection tool to change the coordinate system to WGS 84. Then use the Project Tool to transform them to ED 1950.

Comment: Are you saying some of your points you added are in the correct location, while those that you started with are not in the correct location since you (incorrectly) assumed they were in the ed1950 datum?

Comment: D.Kirk my question was, Think that you have a project (basemap) which uses ed_50 datum. But your coordinates which you took in the field via handheld gps were in wgs84 datum. By mistakenly you treated your field data as if they were obtained in ed_50 and you introduced your data to your arcgis project in ed_50. what must one do to solve this problem? The answer must be something like mkennedys reply. But i can't solve it like that. And edited my question at night about the issue with an attached picture. today i checked my handheld gps and see that manufacurer already set the datum to ed_50.